# How to add files recursively to the master git branch using libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Is there an easy way to add all files in a folder and it's subfolders recursively using libgit2sharp? I tried:

```
r.Stage("*");
```

But it seems to not work properly when there are multiple folders and files. Would the best way to just navigate through all files and add the files like:

```
r.Stage(path_to_file)
```

I would like to add the files to the 'master' branch of a git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the `Stage` methods includes a `IEnumerable<string>` for the files to stage, so you can build that list before passing it to `Stage` instead of calling Stage once per file.

i.e. Grab all the files, [recursively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx), that have the `.cs` extension:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles (repo.Info.WorkingDirectory, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
repo.Stage (files);
```

Need to [create](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-branch#creating-a-branch-pointing-at-the-current-head) a `master` branch

```
repo.CreateBranch("master");
```

Need to checkout the existing `master` branch:

```
repo.Checkout ("master");
```

Comment: let's say some of those .cs files in .gitignore, is it going to be committed if i add them with this way?

Comment: You would need to filter your file list via the IsPathIgnored() method as Stage() is an explicit action, just like doing it via `git`, you can stage/commit files that are in your .gitignore via the `-f` option.